# I want to know is it possible to add a class to an element when it is clicked only with only css?

Tags: html, css

I have a menu which I want to be shown when I click a button and disappeared when I click one more time, I want to do it only with CSS is it possible ?? how ??
Also, I want to know if is it possible to add or delete a class from an element when it is clicked or add a class to another element when an element is clicked ??? and I want to do all of these only with CSS

Comment: I don’t think you can add class on click using ‘just’ css. CSS is mostly for styling. You will atleast need some click event, maybe using JavaScript or Jquery.

Comment: You can't add or remove classes through CSS.

Comment: If you could explain some more exactly what you want to achieve in the way of styling we could help with using inputs (radio or checkbox type) but as others have said you can't add an actual class using CSS, but you can get some styling done in many cases.

Answer (score -1):

For the menu, use a checkbox for the button. A checkbox holds state inside of the checked property. You can hide a checkbox behind something to make it look like something else. You can then use this in the selector to apply styling;

```css
input:checked {

}
```

You cannot add or remove classes using CSS only. Use JavaScript to do this.